# How to do the bytes equivalent of string.translate?

Tags: python, arrays, string, replace

Python provides the `.translate()` method on strings. It accepts a mapping from Unicode codepoints to strings, and uses it to replace any matching codepoint. I'm using this to escape special characters in HTML (`<>&"` to `&lt;` etc.) and URLs (many characters get percent-encoded).

For some reason, the `.translate()` function on `bytes` objects is much weaker: it accepts a `bytes` object of length 256, and uses it as a translation table. I need to do the same HTML and URL escaping on `bytes` objects, but this weaker `.translate()` function can't do it.

Is there another way to do this sort of multiple simultaneous search and replace on `bytes` objects? Doing `.replace()` multiple times seems super inefficient, especially for URL escaping where there are many bytes that need to be escaped.

Comment: Failing everything else, there's always the option of decoding to a string, doing the operations, and then encoding back to bytes (if needed).

Comment: "is much weaker: it accepts a bytes object of length 256, and uses it as a translation table." huh?

Comment: @Kemp The hard part there is handling bytes >= 128. Those are all bytes that need to get URL-escaped. I think it could be made to work, but it will be janky!

Comment: as an aside, you should probably use https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The point I was making is that `string.translate()` can replace a single char with a string of chars, but `bytes.translate()` can only translate single bytes to single bytes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did hope to use to use those libraries. Unfortunately, the requirement is to escape double quotes but not single quotes, and the `html` library doesn't allow that. And it can't handle `bytes` at all. `urlllib` may work for the URL escaping though.

Comment: Why don't you just convert the bytes to a string?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You say "just"...the nontrivial part is that non-ASCII characters aren't guaranteed to be any particular encoding. But I can probably treat it like latin-1 to make it work.